# Trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry

I don't quite understand how to do problems such as 3sin(2θ)=sinθ.

I know that you can put 3sin(2θ) and sinθ in the calculator and look up the values for a given domain, but I don't know how to do them without a calculator.

We have only used degrees and stuff that I find online have radians and it confuses me. I think if someone is able to explain the process or show how they would do the example question I could understand how I should approach these types of problems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Over what interval does it want you to solve the equation?

Comment: 0 to 360 degrees

Answer (score 2):

Hint using basic trigonometric identities:

$$3\sin2t=\sin t\implies3\left(2\sin t\cos t\right)=\sin t\implies \sin t\left(6\cos t-1\right)=0\implies\begin{cases}\sin t=0\\{}\\\text{or}\\{}\\6\cos t-1=0\end{cases}$$

and now you have two simple trigonometric equations to solve.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!

Comment: As you’re new to these types of questions, just remember when solving, to find *all* the solutions between 0 and 360 degrees. You can either use the CAST method to help you and/or draw the graph of sin(t) and see where it is 0 in that interval, and draw separately the graph of 6cost - 1, and see whee it is 0 in that interval